Finding $f(x)$, if $f(f(x))=\frac{x+1}{x+3}$
$$f(f(x))=\frac{x+1}{x+2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1}\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}, x\ne -1, -2.$$
The question is: What is $f(x)$, if $$f(f(x))=\frac{x+1}{x+3}, x\ne -3 ?$$

I don't believe $f(f(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1}\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$.

it's a Mobius transformation. You just need a 2 by 2 matrix   which squares to your coefficient matrix;  as it is symmetric and then positive definite, there is one with real elements.

@Will Jagy Thanks for a good suggestion.

I'm not done with it, but I'd say finding the eigenvalues, putting an orthonormal basis as the columns of  some $P$   with $P^{-1}  = P^T$   along with $P^TAP = D$   diagonal, allows you to use the square roots of the diagonal elements of $D$ as diagonal $D_2,$  then $A_2 = P D_2 P^T$

@AnneBauval But it does. We easily have $f(x) = 1/(x+1) \Rightarrow f(f(x)) = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{x+1} + 1 }$. Then Will's comment explains why this implies the other direction.

@CalvinLin is it true that if $f^2$ is a Möbius transformation, then $f$ is a Möbius transformation, though?

Where did this question come from. Context please

@AlmaArjuna Good point. It doesn't have to be. EG $f(f(x)) = x$ has a lot of non- Mobius tranformation solutions. $\quad$ Though I believe that it will be Mobius if we assume some niceness condition like differentiability.

Why so many have down voted the question for a close?!

@ZAhmed there is no context and no effort shown on your part which goes against the MSE Guidelines.

I couldn't find the tricky solution. However, I can solve it in a long way.
Note: The way you ask is a little bit vague. At below, I find a function $ f(x) $ such that $ f(f(x)) = \frac{x+1}{x+3} $. I didn't discuss whether this function is unique or not.
Answer: $ f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d} $ with $ a = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}} $, $ b = c = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}} $, and $ d = \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}} $.
Derivation: Let $ f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d} $. Then, $ f(f(x)) = \frac{(a^2 + bc)x + (ab + bd)}{(ac + cd)x + (bc + d^2)} $. Therefore, $ f(f(x)) = \frac{x+1}{x+3} $ for a quartet $ (a,b,c,d) $ such that $ a^2 + bc =1 $, $ ab + bd = 1$, $ ac + cd =1 $, and $ bc + d^2 =3$. Since $ ab + bd = ac + cd = 1 $, we have $ b = c $.
Therefore, we have the set of nonlinear equations given by
$$ a^2 + b^2 = 1, \\ b^2 + d^2 = 3 \\ ab + bd=1. $$
First two lines: Using the first two lines and linear algebra (linear in $ a^2 $, $ b^2 $, $ d^2 $), I found $ a^2 = 1 - k $, $ b^2 = k $, and $ d^2 = 3 - k $ for $ k \in \mathbb{R} $.
Third line: From the third line, we have $ \sqrt{k} \cdot \sqrt{1 -k} + \sqrt{k} \cdot \sqrt{3 -k} = 1 $. After taking the square of both sides, we have $ 2k \cdot \sqrt{1 - k} \cdot \sqrt{3 - k} = 1 - 4k + 2k^2 $. After taking the square of both sides once more, we have $ 8 k^2 - 8k + 1 = 0 $. The quadratic equation has two solutions, $ k_1 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} $ and $ k_2 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} $. However, only $ k_1 = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} $ satisfies $ \sqrt{k_1} \cdot \sqrt{1 -k_1} + \sqrt{k_1} \cdot \sqrt{3 -k_1} = 1 $.
Combining what I found above, $ f(f(x)) = \frac{x + 1}{x + 3} $ for $ f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d} $ with the $ (a,b,c,d) $ provided in the answer.

Preamble: We're just finding one solution, not all possible solution. This uses ideas of the Mobius transformation, in particular the fixed point representation. While it's not crucial to know the theory as you can tediously verify the algebra to ascertain that we have a proof, that is the motivation for why this works out and so I'm not showing the derivation.
Notice that we have 2 fixed points when $ x(x+3) = x+1$, namely $ x_1 = -1 + \sqrt{2}, x_2 = -1 - \sqrt{2}$.
This allows us to write
$$ \frac{f(f(x))  - x_1 } { f(f(x)) - x_2 } = ( 3 - 2 \sqrt{2} ) \frac{ x - x_1 } { x - x_2 } .$$
Since $ ( 3 - 2\sqrt{2} ) = ( 1 - \sqrt{2})^2$, one may guess that we have the solution
$$ \frac{ f(x ) -x_1 } { f(x) - x_2 } =  ( 1 - \sqrt{2} ) \frac{ x - x_1 } { x - x_2 }. $$
Making $f(x)$ the subject, we get
$$ f(x) = \frac{ (\sqrt{2} - 2 ) x + \sqrt{2} } { \sqrt{2} x + (3 \sqrt{2} - 2 ) }. $$

The theory here is that

First line: If we apply another Mobius transforamtion such that the fixed points are 0 and $\infty$, then it is clear that we have dilation by factor $k$ (not necessarily positive). It remains to calculate $k$, like by setting $ x = 0, -1 $.
Second line: If $f(f(x))$ is dilation by $k^2$, then $f(x)$ could be obtained by dilation by $k$ of $-k$. Note that there are actually infinitely many solutions here. I believe that with the exception of dilation by $k$ or $-k$, none of the other solutions are "nice".


If you are only looking for one possible solution, then take
$$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt2} - \sqrt{2-\sqrt2}x}{\sqrt{10-\sqrt2} + \sqrt{2+\sqrt2}x}$$

How did you get this?

Hint:
Solve $$A^2=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&3}$$

WolframAlpha takes square root of matrices much faster than me: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sqrt%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C3%7D%7D

As suggested by @Will Jagy
Take Mobius function $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\cdots(*),$ then
$$f(f(x))=\frac{a\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}+b}{c\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}+d}=\frac{(a^2+bc)x+b(a+d)}{c(a+d)x+d^2+bc}=\frac{x+1}{x+3}.$$
We get $$(i): a^2+bc=1,(ii): b(a+d)=1,(iii): c(a+d)=1, (iv): d^2+bc=3$$
From (ii) and (iii) let $b=c=t$, from (i) and (iv) $d^2-a^2=2$.
Again from (ii) and (iii), we get $d=(1/t+2t)/2$ and $a=(1/t-2t)/2$. Finally, (iv)   gives $(1+2t^2)^2+4t^4=12t^2\implies 8t^4-8t^2+1=0.$ We get
$$t=\frac{\pm 1}{2} \sqrt{2\pm \sqrt{2}}.$$
Choosing any of them we can determine $a,b,c,d$. Let
$t=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2},$
we get $a= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4-2\sqrt{2}}}, b=c=\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2}, \frac{4-\sqrt{2}}{2\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}.$
